# Swing -- lazy update

Tags: java, swing, jgoodies

Does Swing have something similar to vaadin's `LAZY` value change mode?

As in "update on every change but after a short delay and cancel the event when the value changes again before the event has finished"?

We have a `float`-type text field that we bind to a property like

```
binder.bindProperty(MY_FOO).converted(floatToString()).to(view.myFoo, ON_KEY_TYPED);
```

where `binder` is a `PresentationModelBinder` and

```
public static BindingConverter<Float, String> floatToString() {
    return BindingConverters.<Float, String>fromModelAs(BindingConverters::toString).andFromViewAs(BindingConverters::parseFloat);
}

static <T> String toString(T anyValue) {
    return (anyValue == null) ? null : anyValue.toString();
}

static <T> String toString(Float floatValue) {
    return (floatValue == null) ? null : String.format("%.2f", floatValue);
}
```

Let's say you want to type `12`

- you type `1`
- Swing immediately exchanges that for `1.00` **and sets the cursor back to the beginning of the field**
- you type `2`
- whoops, you set it to `21`

But it gets worse ...

Let's say you want to write `1.2`

- you type `1`
- Swing immediately exchanges that for `1.00` **and sets the cursor back to the beginning of the field**
- you type `.`
- decimals are (in this app) defined to start with numbers, dot is not a number, so swing erases the invalid input
- you type `2`
- whoops, you set it to `2`

Which is a bad user experience and not what I want.

Looking at `com.jgoodies.binding.binder.ValueModelBindingBuilder`, I see only two options, `ON_FOCUS_LOST` -- which doesn't what we want -- and `ON_KEY_TYPED` -- which very clearly ALSO doesn't what we want.

Is there something (in Swing) that would provide us with the functionality we need or do we have to implement our own?

(And before you ask, YES, we're going to get rid of Swing in a few months.)

Comment: Why don't you try calling the update after the enter key is pressed?

Comment: The behavior, you described, sounds like a bug in your code. Please provide a [mcve] so we can identify them and, probably, provide a fix for it.